# Replacing Variables in Integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have posted questions about this, but they werent clear, here is my **actual misunderstanding**.

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$$

I dont understand, we say:

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$$

Then we say:

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt$$

I want to see how this process works?

We consider

$$f(x) = e^{-x^2}$$

Right? Then we say that:

$$f(t) = e^{-t^2}$$

Right?  Ideally we are replacing x with t correct? Then we say: where R is the whole real axis.

$$I^2 = \int_{R} \int_{R} e^{-(t^2 + x^2)} dtdx$$

But the problem is that now you consider t and x different axes, while before they lay on the same axis.

How does this work?

Comment: What's the question? Is it how why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt$

Comment: @KristofferRyhl ,no. The question is We are using the substitution, $t=x$ then we combine the integral into one with $I^2$, we multiply the integral. After that how are the axes set up? The question is in the last line

Comment: This wikipedia article might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables

Comment: You can either integrate the function $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}, x \mapsto e^{-x^2}$ or integrate the function $g: \Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}, (x,t)\mapsto e^{-(x^2+t^2)}$. In the first case you have an integral on the *real line* and the substitution $x=t$ leads $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(t)\, dt$. Note also that $\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{-(x^2+t^2)}\,dxdt = \int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{-x^2}e^{-t^2}\, dxdt = \int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\, dx\cdot \int_{\Bbb{R}}e^{-t^2}\,dt = I \cdot I$. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Ale, that was a good answer. What I was asking was. What is the graph in the 3D system?

Comment: @anonymous, Again the same question? Why do you always associate variables to axes? You don't need do that!

Comment: I'm sorry @anonymous, but I'm closing this as a duplicate.  You're confusing yourself by thinking of variables the wrong way (as axes); you  need to think of them instead as placeholders for a sum or integral, and develop the intuition which is already shown to you in the many other answers.

Comment: @Ale, here is the issue: 
We defined in the beginning,

$$h(x) = e^{-x^2}$$

$$\therefore, h(y) = e^{-y^2}$$

But so $x$ and $y$ are colinear, lie in the same line. $y = x$ is not necessary. But still, when you make this 3D, $x$ and $y$ cannot have different axes can they? So it cannot be a multivariable function?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$[Elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091925/dummy-variables) it's been explained that the symbol used to denote the "variable of integration" is a *notational device*, not a symbol on which an expression's value depends. This explains why, for example,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}}\, dx
  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^{2}}\, dt
  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha^{2}}\, d\alpha,
$$
(etc., *ad nauseum*).

Integral notation and its usage of dummy variables, incidentally, is an artifact of practical convenience: We write $f(x) = e^{-x^{2}}$ as an *abbreviation* for "$f$ is the (real-valued) function that takes a real number as input, squares it, multiplies by $-1$, and exponentiates". In this verbal description, the input does not have a name, and the function obviously (right?) does not depend on the name on the input. The definite integral above could be written
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f = \int_{\Reals} f \quad (= \sqrt{\pi}),
$$
making explicit its independence of the "dummy variable". (Spivak's *Calculus* uses just this notation.)

Similarly, an equation $g(x, t) = e^{-(t^{2} + x^{2})}$ is an abbreviation for "$g$ is the (real-valued) function that accepts an ordered pair of real numbers, sums their squares, multiplies the result by $-1$, and exponentiates". And the integral identity that seems to be causing confusion can be written
$$
\iint_{\Reals^{2}} g = \left(\int_{\Reals} f\right)^{2} \quad (= \pi).
$$

The points are:

1. The identity in question can be expressed without dummy variables (albeit with an added cost in writing down the definitions of the functions being integrated).
2. Dummy variables are *local to the sum/integral/logical expression in which they occur*. For example, knowing
   $$
   \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \quad\text{or} \quad
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(j)\, dj = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(k)\, dk
   $$
   by no means allows us to deduce that $j = k$: the dummy indices appear in distinct sums/integrals, *outside of which they have no meaning*.
3. When you write
   $$
   \iint_{\Reals^{2}} e^{-(t^{2} + x^{2})}\, dt\, dx
     = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^{2}}\, dt\right)
       \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}}\, dx\right),
   $$
   it *makes no sense* to say "the $t$ on the left is the same as the $t$ on the right"; each $t$ is a dummy variable, a notational device having no meaning outside the respective integral.

Answer (score 0):

The integration variable only has a meaning *inside* the integral (it's like scoping in programming) so variables in different integrals, even if the same symbol is used, are actually unrelated, just confusingly named. In other words,

$${\color{red}\int}_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-{\color{red}x}^2}\,d{\color{red}x}{\color{green}\int}_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-{\color{green}x}^2}\,d{\color{green}x}$$

You see... they look the same but they are not, the integrating variable exists only for the purpose of integral doing the infinitesimal summation over it, it belongs to the integral. They don't lie on the "same axis", the integrals each have their own domain, they can even live in completely different spaces (one could integrate over time, the other over wavelength or something).

You can transform this into one double integral, but you now have to either stick with colors or rename the variable. In any case, the symbol used for the integration variable is completely arbitrary, you can use chinese characters if you want, makes no difference.

Comment: This is really just a substitution.  $x = t$ and $dx = dt$  But after converting it into a double integral, we get that now we have $dxdt$ which means that there exists as $xt$ plane. If that plane exists then one of $x$ or $t$ has to be the independent and the other has to be the dependent variable.. That is the problem?

Comment: @anonymous when you integrate on a plane (x,t) with respect to $x$ and then to $t$, the idea is that you let $t$ fix, and then integrate the function on the $x$ axis. You repeat this operation **for every** value of $t$. Look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5E%7B-%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%7D) to see how the function $e^(-(x^2+t^2))$ looks like and try to understand how the integration works.

Comment: There is no need for one variable being dependent on another if you have a 2D plane. This is not a $x(t)$ function or something. The entire domain, each pair $(x,t)$ is a valid 2D coordinate, both are independent (as they were before when they lived in separate integrals). You can look at it as a surface in 3D, $z=f(x,t)=e^{-x^2-t^2}$ and you have two independent variables.